# String to array in javascript, from base64

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get an array from an effective string. I'm using base64 to encode an already javascript array, i.e, it's being encoded in js array format.

When the browsers decodes the base64, it stores the array as a text.

How do I convert it back to an array?
PHP-side: array = "['My User',1,12],['User 2',1,66]"

var array = ajaxResponse.array;

var array at this point is a string.

Comment: Did you try that with JSON ?

Comment: Can you please post the string that ajax returns you ?

Comment: I go with Dev, its JSON notation, easy to learn if you know javascript, search W3C School you will find tutorials for same :)